# how to convert the data returned from mysql database into json

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, backbone.js

I am trying to learn backbone.JS using WAMP server. when I am trying to retrieve the data from database using fetch function, I couldn't convert the data extracted from database into JSON objects. So here I used Index.php for client side and views.php for server side. Name of my database is dss.Thanks in advance. So here is my code

**index.php**

```
            <!doctype html>
            <html>
                <title>
                    backbone example
                </title>
                <body>
                    <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
                    <script src="underscore.js"></script>
                    <script src="backbone.js"></script>
                    <div id="container">
                    <h1>
                        HELLO
                    </h1>
                        <div id="page">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <script>
                        var User=Backbone.Collection.extend(
                            {
                                url:'backbone sample/users'
                            }
                        );
                        var UserList=Backbone.View.extend(
                        {   

                            el:'#page',
                            render:function()
                            {
                                  var that=this;
                                var users=new User;

                                        users.fetch({

                                            success:function()
                                            {
                                                    alert('success');
                                            }
                                    }
                            );
                                }
                        }
                        );
                         var router=Backbone.Router.extend(
                         {
                             routes:
                                 {
                                 '':'home'
                                 }
                         });

                         var userList=new UserList();
                         var rou=new router();
                         rou.on('route:home',function(){

                               userList.render();

                         });
                         Backbone.history.start();
                    </script>
                </body>
            </html>
```

**users.php**

```
                <?php 

                    $request_method = strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);



                        $a=$_GET['id'];
                        mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("connection error");
                        mysql_select_db("dss") or die("db error");
                        $results=  mysql_query("select * from subscribers where EmailId='$a'");

                ?>
```

Comment: `mysql_` extension is deprecated. Use PDO or MySQLi instead. Also, you might be looking for the `json_encode` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree, get off of mysql_* funcs now and use mysqli_* or PDO.  I don't know anything about backbone or how you can call users.php, but for the PHP I'll use mysqli to echo out the json object:

```
echo json_encode(mysqli_fetch_object($results));
```